# Crystal Reports 2008 connection issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I have migrated Seagate CrystalReports 8 to Visual Studio CrystalReports 2008. 
We have used Oracle drivers for CrystalReports 8 provided by the 3rd party vendor. 
Now we have to use OLEDB for CrystalReports 2008, its throwing errors. Can anyone suggest in this regard?

1. Can any one suggest step by step process for using stored procedures in Crystal reports with OLEDB.
2. Migration from CR 8 to CR2008 (use of OLEDB here)
3. Creating an  stored procedure in Crystal Reports 2008 using OLE DB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the official line from SAP is to test, test, test.  You've missed numerous iterations of CR (8.5, 9, 10, XI, 2008) and each of those iterations had substantial changes.

You don't really use CR to create stored procedures, so I'm not sure what you're asking there.